# Forgetting old WiFi Direct connections

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

Is there a way to forget old WiFi Direct connections(in code)? I need this so as to change who becomes Group owner. I am setting groupOwnerIntent = 15 and yet not becoming Group owner.

Answer (score 5):

If you want just to disconnect from existing `WiFiP2p` connections, then just call `WiFiP2pManager#removeGroup`. Doesn't matter is device GO or peer.

If you are talking about forgetting persistent groups - you can also remove them. But it can only be achieved via reflection. And also no matter is device GO or peer.

```java
    manager.removeGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "removeGroup success");
            deletePersistentGroup(group);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Log.d(TAG, "removeGroup fail: " + reason);
        }
    });
```

Where `manager` is an instance of `WiFip2pManager`. And `deletePersistanteGroup(WiFiP2pGroup group)` is:

```java
    private void deletePersistentGroup(WifiP2pGroup wifiP2pGroup) {
        try {

            Method getNetworkId = WifiP2pGroup.class.getMethod("getNetworkId");
            Integer networkId = (Integer) getNetworkId.invoke(wifiP2pGroup);
            Method deletePersistentGroup = WifiP2pManager.class.getMethod("deletePersistentGroup",
                    WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, int.class, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class);
            deletePersistentGroup.invoke(manager, channel, networkId, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "deletePersistentGroup onSuccess");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "deletePersistentGroup failure: " + reason);
                }
            });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e("WIFI", "Could not delete persistent group", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e("WIFI", "Could not delete persistent group", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("WIFI", "Could not delete persistent group", e);
        }
    }
```

**UPD**

To become a GO you should call `WiFiP2pManager#createGroup()` before sending invites to peers.