# Why did the Wifi Mac Address on my Pixel 2 change (Android Pie)?

Tags: android, mac-address, wifi-direct

I am developing a Wifi Direct application. For weeks, I have had the Wifi MAC address of my test devices (Pixel 2, Android Pie) hardcoded in my application for easy connection.

Last night, I started getting connection errors in a stable piece of code that had been untouched for a while. I noticed that the MAC address in 'About Phone' on my Pixel 2 had changed -- it used to be "42:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" and now it is "40:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX".

More concerning is the fact that the Pixel 2 is advertising its *old* MAC (the one starting with "42") with Wifi Direct. After the Pixel 2 is discovered by a nearby device, trying to connect to either the old address ("42") or the new address ("40") fails immediately in the WifiP2pManager.ActionListener passed to WifiP2pManager.connect with failure reason == WifiP2pManager.ERROR.

So my general questions are...

**1. Why did the WiFi MAC Address on my Pixel 2 change, seemingly at random?**. Note that this is the Wifi MAC displayed in settings, not the dummy value from WifiInfo.getMacAddress()

**2. Why is my phone broadcasting a MAC address different than the one shown in settings when advertising for Wifi Direct peers? Is this an OS-level bug that should be reported? How do I get my phone back in a consistent state (hopefully without a re-image)?**

**3. How can I uniquely identify an advertising Wifi Direct phone like the Pixel 2 during Wifi Direct discovery? WifiP2pDevice.deviceName can be changed by the user. WifiP2pDevice.deviceAddress is apparently NOT static and can be changed by the system. Am I forced to attempt connection and perform some sort of handshake to identify devices, or is it possible to identify a device uniquely (and statically into the future) via Wifi Direct advertisement alone?**

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Can confirm, my pixel 2 and pixel 2 xl just changed both 2.4 and 5ghz mac address.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to forget the previous pairing manually in Wifi Direct settings on the phone. This seemed to reset things. However, the following logistical nightmare for Wifi Direct devs remains:

1. You pair two devices. The devices remember each other's MAC addresses for future automatic connections.
2. The MAC address on one of the devices gets changed by the system without warning/broadcast/developer notification
3. Your devices can no longer pair without forgetting their old connection group. Additionally, advertised MAC address will be incorrect until the old connection group is purged.

I think you can forget the old group programmatically, but you may have to use [reflection...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653707/forgetting-old-wifi-direct-connections)